# Personalize colors in lasagna plot using longCatEDA

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data, longitudinal

A lasagna plot with 3 categorical variables can be plot using this code and works fine

```
[![library(longCatEDA)
library(colorspace)
library(RColorBrewer)
set.seed(642531)
y <- matrix(sample(1:3, 500, replace=TRUE), 100, 5)
set.seed(963854)
times <- matrix(runif(600, 1, 3), 100, 6)

# times must be cumulative
times <- t(apply(times, 1, cumsum))
lc <- longCat(y, times=times)

par(mfrow=c(1,1), bg='white', mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 10.1), xpd=TRUE)


cols <- longCatPlot(lc,  colScheme='rainbow', legendBuffer=0, groupBuffer=0,main='How to personalize colors?')

legend(16.5, 100, legend=lc$Labels, lty=1, col=cols, lwd=2)][1]][1]
```

[image]

But I'm trying to personalize the colors:

1.Red

2.Yellow

3.Green

I could not find how to use specific colors, so I tried the default palettes and the best I could do was using the "rainbow" scheme.
There are also the `colorspace` and the `RColorBrewer` but none of them includes the 3 colors I need (red, yellow and green in that order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `colScheme`-argument use `cols` instead:

```r
library(longCatEDA)
set.seed(642531)
y <- matrix(sample(1:3, 500, replace=TRUE), 100, 5)
set.seed(963854)
times <- matrix(runif(600, 1, 3), 100, 6)

# times must be cumulative
times <- t(apply(times, 1, cumsum))
lc <- longCat(y, times=times)

par(mfrow=c(1,1), bg='white', mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 10.1), xpd=TRUE)

cols <- longCatPlot(lc, cols = c("red", "yellow", "green"), legendBuffer=0, groupBuffer=0,main='How to personalize colors?')

legend(16.5, 100, legend=lc$Labels, lty=1, col=c("red", "yellow", "green"), lwd=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>